# Add to a stack with a regex

Tags: c++, regex

I'm learning regex and C++ and I want to make a postfix expression. To do this I want to separate my string like this :

```
String : 56*((6+2)/(8-7)* 2^3)
List : 56 | * | ( | (| 6 | + | 2 | ) | / | ( ....
```

Actually I have :

```
void Stack::findIT() {
    std::string var = "56*((6+2)/(8-7)* 2^3)";

    std::string str("56*((6+2)/(8-7)* 2^3)");
    std::regex r("([0-9]*|[+*\\-\\/%]|[()])");
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_search(str, m, r);
    for(auto v: m) std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

I want to pill a :
std::stack _operators;
std::stack _operands;

And to do this extract the string with the Regex
But why when I use this code I have empty string ?

Comment: And... your question is?

Comment: You probably want `[0-9]+` as empty number seems wrong.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It seems your code [does not reproduce your problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KpRkxRK6PXlcGUSY).

Comment: When I run your code it prints out `56\n56`, is that what you expect?

Comment: Also no need to put parentheses round the whole regex as match number `0` already returns the whole expression.

Comment: I want to put each match in a new list with push but before I try to print all what the regex found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `std::regex r("([0-9]*|[+*\\-\\/%]|[()])");`, empty string is matched.

You probably want: `"[0-9]+|[+*/%^()-]"`

You also have to iterate for your search:

```
std::string str("56*((6+2)/(8-7)* 2^3)");
std::regex r("[0-9]+|[+*/%^()-]");
std::smatch m;
while (std::regex_search(str, m, r)) {
    std::cout << m[0] << std::endl;
    str = m.suffix();
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/6ZxqKW)

Comment: I can't compile this I have found this on stack overflow but I need to passed str.c_str() and for m I dont know. Cuz it didn't compile EDIT : Its compile but it say that str need to be a const and that std::smatch is not compatible

Comment: @BenjaminSx: I give demo link, so I don't understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

To collect all the matches in a string you should really be using `std::sregex_iterator`.

I would recomend you use raw string literals so you don't have to worry about escaping in your regex: `R"~()~"` (expression goes in the middle, no escapes required).

I changed you regex slightly. In character sets you have to put `-` at the beginning or end (otherwise it's a range separator). I also added the ability to read decimal numbers.

```
std::string str("56*((6+2)/(8-7)* 2^3)");
std::regex r(R"~(\d+(:?\.\d+)?|[-+*\/%^]|[()])~");

std::sregex_iterator m_end;
std::sregex_iterator m(std::begin(str), std::end(str), r);

for(; m != m_end; ++m)
    std::cout << m->str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: I understand but all this is new so I tryhard to understand thanks for your help